# multipart nodes anchors for dividers

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, nodes

How can a node be positioned at the center/edge of a part in a multipart node using relative positioning?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=center,draw,shape=rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,rectangle split parts=3, text width=2cm] (A) at (1.5,3) 
{one\nodepart{two}two\nodepart{three}three};
\node[draw,shape=circle] (E) at (2.7,1) {$E$};
\node[draw,shape=circle] (C) at (3.7,1) {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the desired result:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=center,draw,shape=rectangle split,rectangle split horizontal,rectangle split parts=3, text width=2cm] (A) at (1.5,3) 
{$m$\nodepart{two}$0 \ldots 0$\nodepart{three}$r$};
\node[draw,shape=circle] (E) [below=of A.two split south] {$E$};
\node[draw,shape=circle] (C) [below=of A.three south] {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The TikZ manual version 2.10, page 453 displays the anchors for the vertical `split rectangle`. You have to reinterpret for the horizontal version.

Comment: not quite, I edited the code to make it more copy-pasteable. The E node should be horizontally aligned with (but appear below) the separator line separating partnode two and three. and C should horizontally be at the center of partnode three and also appear below (same y-coord as E)

Comment: I edited my answer. I hope it's ok now. `:)`

Comment: thank you so much, I didn't know about the split option.

Comment: @Mish: don't forget to upvote the answer (using the up arrow)- this gives Count Zero 10 reputation points, and is the best way to say thanks :) Also remember to upvote other answers that you find helpful on the site